# Integrate OAuth2 to my Web API

Tags: api, oauth-2.0

I created an API for my Web app, and now i have an idea to integrate OAuth2 protocol to secure access to my API. it is possible or i might re-write all the API ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completly possible to integrate an OAuth2 layer, but this will depend on how you wrote your API. Let's start from the begining.

What language are you using?
Depending on this, there is many components to integrate an OAuth security layer.

However if you want to do it yourself, I'll show you how I did it in some project.

The implementation of this protocol involved, in my case, 4 tables: `oauth_access_token` (in which the access tokens of users are stored), `oauth_client` (clients who can get access tokens and refresh tokens), `oauth_refresh_token` (in which are stored the refresh tokens, which can eventually be exchanged for a access token) and `oauth_auth_code`.

After that, you need to create at least 2 endpoints to your API:

- http://api.yourdomain.com/oauth/authorize- this endpoint is for the clients request access to your API (like the authorization page from facebook, twitter, etc)
- http://api.yourdomain.com/oauth/access_token - this one is after the authorization, the clients request an access token. At the end of this procees the client will be redirected to a provided callback URL.

Now you need to create a CRUD that will be used by developers to register their applications, the ones they will integrate with your app. Remeber to ask about the callback URL. After the registration you will provide them a clientID and a clientSecret. With this credentials in hand they can ask for an authorization.

Remember that your API must check for an `Authorization` header, wiht the access_token. If it's valid than you can grant access to you API.

Probably this layer  will be checked on all your API calls, so you will need a middleware. Depending on which language or framework that you are using, this will be very simple to implement.

Hope that this help with something :)

Comment: thanks so much , it's helpful ,
It is a REST API written in Java